# How can I increase the size of the displayed text using a library like Allegro? C

Tags: c, linux, font-size, allegro, allegro5

How can I change the size of the displayed font to display the following entry:

```
al_draw_textf(font, al_map_rgb(204, 255, 255), WIDTH / 2, 50,\
              ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "%d : %d", pl1.scope, pl2.scope);
```

Created a standard ASCII font which I am trying to resize.

```
ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_create_builtin_font();
```

[Display of the players' score. (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swSHG.png)

*This is the first game, I didn't do anything except console programs before.*

---

Comment: Doesn't `al_create_builtin_font()` get you default font. Use `al_load_font()` to set font size.

Comment: @SparKot    Thus, as I understand it, I cannot change the size of the standard font?

Comment: @SparKot       Your answer really helped me, if you have the opportunity could you post your answer. I've been looking for answers on this platform for quite some time, I wouldn't mind getting 15 points to vote for good answers which I've come across a lot in the past 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As [al_create_builtin_font() - liballeg](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.0.9/font.html#al_create_builtin_font) points out:

> ALLEGRO_FONT *al_create_builtin_font(void)
>
> Creates a monochrome bitmap font (8x8 pixels per character).
>
> This font is primarily intended to be used for displaying information
> in environments or during early runtime states where no external font
> data is available or loaded (e.g. for debugging).

2. In order to resize fonts load fonts from the local/system repo.

[al_load_font()](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.0.9/font.html#al_load_font) :

```c
ALLEGRO_FONT *al_load_font(char const *filename, int size, int flags)
```

3. Package your fonts with the game, it becomes easier to load them.